# minimal self-contained WPF/C# for generating splash screen that displays for x seconds

Tags: c#, splash-screen, csc

I'm wondering, why doesn't my splash screen disappear after x seconds in the code below?  In C#, I start a thread, that waits x seconds, then tries to dispatch a close() to the splash window while its being shown on the screen.

```
// FILE: splashy.cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Threading;

namespace Splashy
{
    class MySplash
    {
        Window win;

        public void Show()
        {
            var mem     = new MemoryStream(
                            ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlstr));

            win         = (Window)XamlReader.Load(mem);
            (new Thread(CloseIt)).Start();
            win.Show();
        }

        public void CloseIt() {
            Thread.Sleep(4*1000);
            //MessageBox.Show("CLOSE");
            win.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => win.Close());
        }

        static string xmlstr = @"
<Window
  xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'
  xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'
  Name='WindowSplash'
  Title='My Splash Window...'
  WindowStyle='None'
  WindowStartupLocation='CenterScreen'
  Background='White'
  ShowInTaskbar ='true'
  Width='350' Height='130'
  ResizeMode = 'NoResize' >

<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType='{x:Type Label}'>
            <Setter Property='FontFamily' Value='Consolas'/>
            <Setter Property='Background' Value='Blue'/>
            <Setter Property='Foreground' Value='AntiqueWhite'/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>

<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height='Auto'/>
    <RowDefinition Height='*'/>
    <RowDefinition Height='Auto'/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width='Auto'/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width='*'/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<Label
    Grid.ColumnSpan='2'
    Grid.Row='0'
    Content='MyApplication 1.0'
    FontWeight='Bold'
    FontFamily='Consolas'
    Background='AntiqueWhite'
    Foreground='Black'/>

<Label
    Grid.ColumnSpan='2'
    Grid.Row='2'
    Content=''
    FontWeight='Bold'
    FontFamily='Consolas'
    Background='AntiqueWhite'
    Foreground='Black'/>


<Label
    Grid.Column='0'
    Grid.Row='1'
    FontFamily='Webdings' Content='&#xc2;' FontSize='80' />

<StackPanel
    Grid.Row='1'
    Grid.Column='1'
    Background='Blue'
    >
    <Label Content='Programmer: John Smith'/>
    <Label Content='Email:      john.smith@gmail.com'/>
    <Label Content='Dates:      2017'/>
</StackPanel>

</Grid>

</Window>
";

    } //end-class

    class MyApp 
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            (new MySplash()).Show();
        }
    } //end-class
} //end-namespace
```

Here's an Example of what my csc.exe command line looks for compiling above c# code from system(...) inside of console mode c++ application:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe 
/out:splashy.exe 
/nologo  
/target:winexe 
splashy.cs 
/reference:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\Framework64\v4.0.30319\WPF\presentationframework.dll" 
/reference:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\Framework64\v4.0.30319\WPF\windowsbase.dll" 
/reference:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\Framework64\v4.0.30319\WPF\presentationcore.dll" 
/reference:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.Xaml.dll"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your program does nothing to pump the message queue and dispatch window messages to windows. So your attempt to close the window, which sends a `WM_CLOSE` message to the window, has no effect.

The easiest way to solve this in your example would be to use `win.ShowDialog()` instead of `win.Show()`. The `ShowDialog()` method supersedes whatever message-pump loop is already running, replacing it with its own (it does this so it can intercept user-input messages that shouldn't be dispatched to other windows while the modal dialog is up). But it doesn't require that there already be a message-pump loop, and the one it runs will suffice to receive your `WM_CLOSE` and close the window.

If you want to do it more properly, you can add an `Application` object to your sample and call `Application.Run()` to provide the message-pump loop. You might want to do this if you at some point expect to require showing multiple windows or otherwise require a non-modal UI.

Comment: Thanks! After rewriting and adding "Application.Run(win)" it works.

Answer (score 0):

These are the modifications that worked for me:

```
// FILE: splashy.cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Threading;

namespace Splashy
{
    class MySplash
    {
        Window win;

        public Window CreateWindow()
        {
            var mem     = new MemoryStream(
                              ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlstr));
            win         = (Window)XamlReader.Load(mem);
            (new Thread(CloseIt)).Start();
            return win;
        }

        public void CloseIt() {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
                win.Close();
            });
        }

        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application app    = new Application();
            MySplash    splash = new MySplash();
            Window      win    = splash.CreateWindow();
            app.Run(win);
        }

        static string xmlstr = @"
            <Windows ...> 
            <!-- ...  Omitted to save space ... --> 
            <Window/>
        ";

    } //end-class
} //end-namespace
```